# Computing expected frequencies for gamma distribution R VS Python

Tags: python, gamma-distribution, scipy

I am tryng to "translate" from R to Python a code that computed expected frequencies from the Gamma distribution.

More specifically, I have this line of code:

`(pgamma(3,shape=a.est,rate=l.est)-pgamma(0,shape=a.est,rate=l.est))*200` that calculate expected frequencies from a gamma distribution of size 200, and shape `a.est <- <-((med.gam)^2)/var.gam` and rate `l.est<-avg.gam / var.gam`.

I found out in Python the `scipy.stats` package, and this is my implementation:

`(gamma.cdf(3, a_est, 1/l_est) - gamma.cdf(0, a_est, 1/l_est)) * 200`

However, the results are quite different between R and Python, this makes me think I am making some sort of mistakes.
Is this way to calculate expected frequencies in python correct?

Comment: This question is probably gonna be closed because it is off-topic, but to help you further, why not plot some of those curves, or individual values to debug and find out how those functions work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you read the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html):

```
gamma takes a as a shape parameter for .
....
cdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=1)
```

The parameter that comes after the shape is location, not scale. You need to do:

```
a_est = 3
l_est = 2
from scipy.stats import gamma, norm
gamma.cdf(6, a_est, scale=1/l_est)
0.9994777419499671
```

In R:

```
pgamma(6,shape=a_est,rate=l_est)
[1] 0.9994777
```